# Set provisioning profile with Delphi app for OSX

Tags: macos, delphi, provisioning-profile

I have an app created for the OSX plaform, created with Delphi 11.2. When I set the Configuration setting to Application Store, the app compiles fine. When I press the Deploy button, the app is deployed to my Mac, creating both the "app" and "pkg" files without problems. If I run the "pkg" installer, the app is installed on my Mac and runs as it should.

However, if I try to upload the "pkg" file to the Apple Store Connect, or run "Verify" in the Apple Transporter app, I get the error "Cannot be used with TestFlight because the bundle "" is missing a provisioning profile. ...". I have created the provisioning profile on my developer account, downloaded it to my Mac, and it appears that XCode sees the profile.

I also have the needed certificates set in Delphi for the MacOS 64-bit settings, otherwise the compile/deploy of the app would fail.

Any idea what I am missing here to get Delphi's OSX Application Store build to see the provisioning profile?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [this report I recently filed](https://quality.embarcadero.com/browse/RSP-40302), the workaround is to:

1. Locate the matching App Store provisioning profile on the Mac, or download it from the Apple Developer website where your certs and profiles are
2. Copy the provisioning profile to the project folder, and rename it
   embedded.provisionprofile
3. Add embedded.provisionprofile to the Deployment for macOS, with a Remote Path value of: Contents\
4. Deploy

Now the app should be able to be submitted to TestFlight